# How to remove document from a collection, IF there are 'n' documents in the same collection with the same 'x' field value as deleting document

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongo db with some collections. I would like to delete a document with specific, let's say 'x' field, only, if in the same collection are present 'n' number of documents with the same value of the 'x' field (same as deleting document). In addition, I want to delete those documents, which are older then given 'y' date (that's easy, just saying).

I would like to know if this is possible with one statement. The easy way would be to find those documents, with the same 'x' field value, check if the number of them is greater then 'n', if it is, delete those which are older then 'y' date && delete only (number of found documents) - 'n'; and make it via two/three statement. But again, is it possible with one statement?

EDIT:

```
db.collection.find()
```

should result in: https://pastebin.com/tEbN1U9t

```
db.collection.DESIRED_COMMAND()
```

> DESIRED_COMMAND() - Deletes all documents with "Custom_Id" field == 1, [TimeStamp] < 20 Jan
>   2012, BUT LEAVE AT LEAST, let's say, 3 documents with "Custom_Id" == 1

should result in: https://pastebin.com/Vyq9npzB

What I am looking for is DESIRED_COMMAND()

Comment: Hard to follow without a simple concrete example, do you mind providing a set of input documents and the expected output from the above operation? This would go a long way in clarifying your problem and attract potentially good solutions.

Comment: @chridam sure, I will do that. However, I thought I made it pretty straightforward.

Comment: I don't think it answers your goal of "one statement" precisely but if you are using MongoDB > 4.0 you can consider using transactions: https://docs.mongodb.com/master/core/transactions/.